# order by problem in date type

Tags: mysql

Same like date_format(ExpenditureDate,'%d-%m-%Y') between '01-01-2011' AND '31-01-2011' ,

Also i cant able to check cond with between, ????

ExpenditureDate  --  DATE type[image]

Below query Displaying correctly , latest dates are coming top and one by one

```
SELECT ExpenditureName,ExpenditureAmount,ExpenditurePlaceTypeWhome,ExpenditureDate FROM tblexpenditure WHERE Status=1 AND EntryUser=2 ORDER BY ExpenditureDate DESC
```

but if i add date_format(ExpenditureDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as ExpenditureDate

Then loose my proper order, it displaying inordered

```
SELECT ExpenditureName,ExpenditureAmount,ExpenditurePlaceTypeWhome,date_format(ExpenditureDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as ExpenditureDate FROM tblexpenditure WHERE Status=1 AND EntryUser=2 ORDER BY ExpenditureDate DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a box running mysql to test, but I try to avoid naming the string formated displayable 'expenditure date' the same as the one you sort by.

Answer (score 2):

They probably come sorted, but by lexicographical order of the dates rather than chronological order. It's normal since you sort on the ExpenditureDate alias, which is a string containing the formatted date.
Use another alias :

```
SELECT ExpenditureName,ExpenditureAmount,ExpenditurePlaceTypeWhome,date_format(ExpenditureDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as FormattedExpenditureDate FROM tblexpenditure WHERE Status=1 AND EntryUser=2 ORDER BY ExpenditureDate DESC
```

If you really want to keep the same alias, you might also try this :

```
SELECT ExpenditureName,ExpenditureAmount,ExpenditurePlaceTypeWhome,date_format(ExpenditureDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as ExpenditureDate FROM tblexpenditure WHERE Status=1 AND EntryUser=2 ORDER BY tblexpenditure.ExpenditureDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL seems to sort on the formatted value.  Try writing

```
...,date_format(ExpenditureDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as FormattedExpenditureDate ...
```

but leave the `ORDER BY` clause with the column name.